# Restangular - removing unwanted datas from json objects returned from server

Tags: json, angularjs, restangular

I have created an restangular application which returns a Student object details json from the server, the application is working fine , but the problem is that it is returning student details with other unwanted datas along with it as shown below

**Expected Json**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "Alex",
  "lastName": "Sam",
  "age": 22
}
```

**Actual Json**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "Alex",
  "lastName": "Sam",
  "age": 22,
  "route": "print",
  "reqParams": null,
  "$fromServer": true,
  "parentResource": null,
  "restangularCollection": false
}
```

**script**

```
var baseAccount = Restangular.one('print',"Alex");

baseAccount.get().then(function (account) {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(account));
    $scope.data = account; // Only one account
});
```

**java**

```
@GET
@Path("/print/{name}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Student produceJSON( @PathParam("name") String name ) {

    Student st = new Student(name, "Sam",22,1);

    return st;

}
```

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#how-can-i-access-the-unrestangularized-element-as-well-as-the-restangularized-one

Answer (score 4):

Take in to account that this info is necessary if you want that Restangular provide services like update or delete this object through Rest services.

For removing this data you have to unrestangularize the object, it's done by stripRestangular().

```
var rawObject = Restangular.stripRestangular(restangularizedObject);
```